# Required to read a remote file using url and convert it to json

Tags: angular

In my project i need to read a file (csv) fro url eg:[link](http://insight.dev.schoolwires.com/HelpAssets/C2Assets/C2Files/C2ImportCalEventSample.csv)
and covert it to json. i know how to read a local file using input tag please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first :

```
npm install xlsx
```

Then in your component :

```
jsonData:any;

DownloadFile()
{
    ctx = this;
    url = "exemple.com/file.xlsx";
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => {
        ctx.jsonData = convertToJson(res.toString());
    });
}

convertToJson(bstr) : any
{
    let wb: XLSX.WorkBook;
    let wsname: string;
    let ws: XLSX.WorkSheet;

    wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
    /* grab first sheet */
    wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];
    ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];

    //this is the json data you are looking for
    data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));

    return data;
}
```

I hope this helps

you cand find more information on the xlsx library [here](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)